# Over the Internet or On the Internet?

Tags: word-choice

I have come across both the phrases - *'on the internet'* and *'over the internet.'*

I'm pretty sure that both are correct but then **which to use when?**

**Please note,** I'm well aware of **all over the Internet** which I'm not concerned about.

Comment: This might just be a matter of personal preference, but it's hard to say for sure. For me, it might come down to which verb I'm using. I would probably say, "I **found** this *on* the internet," and maybe, "I **got** this *over* the internet, but I wouldn't correct someone that switched it around, or used the two terms more interchangeably.

Comment: Indeed. I think at this stage of internet-based language use they are more less interchangeable. But @Maulik V try looking at the contexts in which each was used. Was "over" used more for downloading/retrieving/obtaining, for example, and "on" for activities performed online? Might be an idea to provide examples of contexts in your question.

Comment: I think it would come down to the basic sense of *on* vs. *over*. The *on* would give a sense of "being situated on*. The *over* might be better for the verbs that hint of a movement. Thus, *found* is likely to be used with *on*, whereas the use of *over* might go well with verbs like *get*, *send*, *deliver*, etc. But this is not clear cut.

Comment: so what does *all over the internet* mean?

Comment: @Ooker *all over* is the phrase to emphasize its presence.

Comment: @MaulikV is it similar to *it's on the internet already*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would generally use "on the Internet" when I'm talking about the Internet as a location:

> I found this picture on the Internet.

I would use "over the Internet" when I'm talking about the Internet as a means of content delivery:

> I downloaded this picture over the Internet.

Comment: Cannot it be *I downloaded this picture **from** the Internet?*

Comment: Also, "to **sell** goods **over the Internet**"