# We see things ON / IN / AT the internet?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following prepositions is correct when talking about seeing something on internet?

> You can see it ON / IN / AT the internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We usually use *on* with technical communication devices or programmes:

- on the television
- on the phone
- on the radio
- on the news
- on the loudspeaker
- on my walkman
- on my stereosystem
- on my ipod
- on the internet

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

"On" is the correct word. In general, things are on the internet.